# React-Native: Constantly get XCode break stops

Tags: react-native, xcode9

I have upgraded an older React Native project to 0.47, 0.48 and then 0.49.x. Since I've done so, I keep getting XCode breaking at random moments with the following breakpoint (sometimes others).

[image]

My dependencies

`"dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^2.1.0",
    "cheerio-without-node-native": "^0.20.2",
    "diacritic": "0.0.2",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "harmony-proxy": "^1.0.1",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^2.3.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "lodash.mergewith": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.sorteduniq": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.sorteduniqby": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.union": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.unionwith": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.17",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.3",
    "normalizr-immutable": "0.0.4-beta12",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-immutable-proptypes": "^2.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-intl-redux": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native": "^0.49.3",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.7.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "5.1.3-beta",
    "react-native-cookies": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.5.2",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.3.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.17.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-immutable-list-view": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-invertible-scroll-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.3.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "2.0.0-rc",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-photo-view": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.7",
    "react-native-sglistview": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-share": "^1.0.23",
    "react-native-store": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.12",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.13",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.5",
    "react-swipeable-views-native": "^0.12.5",
    "realm": "^1.13.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.3",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-middleware-oneshot": "^0.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-persist-immutable": "^4.3.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^4.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "route-parser": "0.0.5",
    "webstomp-client": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0-beta.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.8.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
    "commitizen": "^2.9.6",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "flow": "^0.2.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.56.0",
    "immutablediff": "^0.4.3",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-serializer-enzyme": "^1.0.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-intl-cra": "^0.2.8",
    "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "redux-debounce": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-debounced": "^0.4.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12",
    "sinon": "^4.0.0",
    "why-did-you-update": "0.0.8"
  }`

Other symptoms:
- react-native run-ios completes with BUILD SUCCEEDED but the app opens and immediately closes on the simulator (works ok from Xcode)

In order to eliminate "old file issues", I created a new react-native project and copied over the newly created xcodeproj file over. To no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So it worked in .47 and .48 but not .49? The big breaking change in .49 is that now your root file should be a single index.js instead of a index.ios.js and index.android.js.

Comment: I already made that change. I have this problem across all those versions, unfortunately. My guess is it's something to do with one or more of the linked libraries, but it's hard for me to debug this stuff.

Comment: ah... you can try unlinking all of them and re-linking 1 by 1 and seeing if it builds and where it's breaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the resolution was executing `pod init` in the ios directory.

The script identifies some erroneous links that don't become apparent in Xcode. Probably the result of react-native upgrades over a significant amount of time.